# AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping LambdaTrigger UPDATE_FAILED

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

`"AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping LambdaTrigger UPDATE_FAILED: Resource handler returned message: \"Invalid request provided: Received Exception while reading from provided stream. Rate exceeded for shard shardId-000000000004`

One of the cloudformation template is failing with the above error. The kinesis stream which the lambda is listening to is having noOfShards = 2.

I am not able to understand the error and what will be the probable solution to this?

Cloud formation template -

```
LambdaTrigger:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Properties:
      StartingPosition: LATEST
      EventSourceArn: !Sub
        - arn:aws:kinesis:${region}:${accountId}:stream/${streamName}
        - region: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
          accountId: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
          streamName: !Ref KinesisStreamName
      FunctionName: !Ref KinesisReader
```

It is picking the correct name of the stream, accounted
And there are two shards in this kinesi stream

// ScreenShots for recent changes

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the template and what changes do you introduce for the update?

Comment: Marcin, I have updated the question

Comment: What update do you do? What was your template before update, and what is the new version?

Comment: I have added the screen shots for the change @Marcin